Is there a way to run LMC/Little Man Computer code in VS code?
Is there a way to run LMC/Little Man Computer code in VS code as I am trying to build something in that language but I do not know the name or means of installation does anyone know a solution or have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Use a web version?  https://peterhigginson.co.uk/LMC/ -or- https://blog.paulhankin.net/lmc/lmc.html -or- https://www.101computing.net/LMC/

I'll add my own to that list of web versions: https://trincot.github.io/lmc.html
